# what is the distance function used by the Function Voronoi in scipy.spatial?

Tags: distance, voronoi, metric

I would like to know the closeness metric i.e. euclidean or manhattan distance that is used by the function Voronoi in segregating a given area into Voronoi regions. Is it possible to tell this function to use my own custom metric for decided the closeness to a voronoi center?

I tried looking in the source package but did not find the source code behind the definition of the function

```
class scipy.spatial.Voronoi(points, furthest_site=False, incremental=False, qhull_options=None)
```

any help would be appreciated!!.

Answer (score 0):

A simple norm2 function in N Dimensions.

```
distance = sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2+...+nth_dim^2)
```

if you want to use a weighted function for example poisson voronoi in 3D (with radius of each point also called radical voronoi) you can use an extended 4D vector for each voronoi point:

```
points=np.array([[x_1,y_1,z_1,sqrt(c^2-rad_1^2)],
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 [x_i,y_i,z_i,sqrt(c^2-rad_i^2)],
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 [x_n,y_n,z_n,sqrt(c^2-rad_n^2)]);
```

where c is a arbitrary big number which none of the fourth dimension elements gets zero.

at the end sorry, I don't know if you can make your own custom metric.
cheers